# How to organize site with CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

For example, I've created next structure

```
application
js
css 
system
```

Standart `.htaccess` deny access to any files from `js` or `css` folders.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|img|styles|js)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

How would you advise to organize site structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using the same file structure as yours but have not considered them in my .htaccess file and it works. My .htaccess file looks like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

I by echoing the base url then adding the other directories. E.g. for css files it would be

```
href="<?php echo base_url()?>css/filename.css"
```

Comment: can you post the url which does not work? Is it appntame/controller that doesn't work?

Comment: sorry I've forgotten to add <?php echo base_url(); ?> in scripts path. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

I've wondered about how to best organize my assets too.

When starting out with CodeIgniter, I read that anything specific to one app should go inside the application folder, and stuff related to multiple apps should go in the systems folder, so I used to put my assets in application/assets/...

Not long ago I read a recommendation to put your assets in folder in the root, either

```
/css
/images
/js
```

or

```
/assets/css
/assets/images
/assets/js
```

On my current project, I've decided to go with the latter structure.

I'm not quite sure what your question regarding the .htaccess file is?

Comment: This is two questions in one :) If I could, I'd mark your answer as correct either. Thank you for hint, I'm moving files to assets.

Answer (score 0):

I've your looking for ideas on how to organize your Controllers in CodeIgniter, I've written a blog post on my thoughts for a best-practices approach to doing so. Check it out:
http://caseyflynn.com/2011/10/26/codeigniter-php-framework-how-to-organize-controllers-to-achieve-dry-principles/